# Add song to Spotify Queue through Spotify API

Tags: api, spotify

With the new endpoint /player of the Spotify Web API we can now control the playback of a Spotify Client. With the endpoint https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play we can add a song to be played.

I was wondering if there is a way to utilize the new endpoints to add a song to the players' queue. I'm planning to write an app to let multiple guests request songs that can be played through Spotify on a party.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 14):

Okay, I found myself an answer. This feature is right now not supported. But it seems that this is not too far away on their roadmap.

https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/462

Comment: "not too far" if the scale you're using is the lifespan of the universe

Comment: No change over two years later. I hope they eventually add this.

Comment: Haha nailed it @Jack'

Answer (score 3):

I might be wrong but could it be a workaround to use a playlist in which you add/reorder tracks as much as you want during its playback ?

I know you can do this with the API :

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/

Comment: The client will only pick up that a song was added if playback was started from the client rather than from code, unfortunately.  But I figure this is the way to go for now

Answer (score 3):

They finally added the ability to add a song to a user's queue! Try it out [here](https://developer.spotify.com/console/post-queue/)